# aggregate data based on ID and month depending on another column (pre vs post)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

Assuming the below dataframe in python, how do I check the **pre_hit_price** and the **post_hit_price** (average or sum) for each Name?

(In SAS we could use first. and last. to figure this out)

```
d = {'Name': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'], 'price' : [0,1,2,3,2,4,6,8] , 'month': [201901, 201902, 201903, 201904, 201901, 201902, 201903, 201904] , 'hit': [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

example_df:

[image]

- the Name is repeated across months
- the hit column is the differentiator
- **pre_hit_price** should be 0 for A and 2 for B
- **post_hit_price** should be (1+2+3) for A and (4+6+8) for B. (inclusive of hit month)

output_df:

[image]

Comment: Equivalent option in pandas for first. and last. can be drop_duplicate “keep” option. You can pass “first” or “last” here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1

Use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) + [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).
The way to get the Boolean series to group (`groupby_hit`) is explained in **method 2**. You just have to add the use of [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
groupby_hit=df.groupby('Name').hit.cumsum().eq(0).map({False:'post_hit_price',True:'pre_hit_price'})
new_df=df.groupby(['Name',groupby_hit],sort=False).price.sum().unstack().rename_axis(columns=None)
print(new_df)

      pre_hit_price  post_hit_price
Name                               
A                 0               6
B                 2              18
```

## **Method 2**

Creating two DataFrame 
based on the appearance of `1` in the `hit` column and the value of the `Name` column using [`DataFrame.groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) with [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)( see **Detail**). Then use [`Groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) + [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
prehit_mask=df.groupby('Name').hit.cumsum().eq(0)
df_pre=df[prehit_mask]
df_post=df[~prehit_mask]
new_df=pd.concat([df_pre.groupby('Name').price.agg(pre_hit_price='sum'),
                  df_post.groupby('Name').price.agg(post_hit_price='sum')],
                  axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
      pre_hit_price  post_hit_price
Name                               
A                 0               6
B                 2              18
```

---

If you use **Pandas <0.25.0**:

```
new_df=pd.concat([df_pre.groupby('Name').price.agg({'pre_hit_price':'sum'}),
                  df_post.groupby('Name').price.agg({'post_hit_price':'sum'})],
                  axis=1)
```

**Detail:**

```
print(prehit_mask)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: hit, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks @ansev. It did work. Flagged as the solution.

Comment: also, how would i limit the lookback / lookahead period ? eg. if I have data for 2 years and want to limit the pre period to 6 months and post to 3 months ?